# JavaScript 'score counter' to work across various pages on website

Tags: javascript, html, counter, point

I'm trying to 'gamify' my website to engage learners. I am still incredibly new to JavaScript so I apologize in advance. There are dozens of similar articles, but none that match my needs closely and I have tried and failed to implement a fix with other similar questions - sorry (I have tried hard!)

Across approximately 10 pages, inside the navbar, I want to insert a counter. The code below is using the ID 'score-counter' to do this, and I've tried using localStorage to retain the score of that learner across each page. I've managed to get it to work (somewhat) but instead of adding 10 to the original value, it's creating an entirely new counter and starting from scratch.

I want each button to only be clickable once (per page refresh) so I have tried to remove the eventListener after each button is clicked. I also want a straight-forward way to add more buttons to the counter system, so I've tried to keep it to the two simple classes 'increment-button' and 'first-click'.

```html
<button class="first-click increment-button">Add 10 to the value!</button>
<div id="score-counter">0</div> <!-- DISPLAYS THE COUNT -->
```

```js
let score = localStorage.getItem("score") || 0;
const incrementButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".increment-button");
const scoreCounter = document.getElementById("score-counter");
scoreCounter.textContent = score;

for (let button of incrementButtons) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(this.classList.contains("first-click")) {
            score += 10;
            localStorage.setItem("score", score);
            this.classList.remove("first-click");
        }
    });
}
```

---

The output currently keeps doing this: 201010101010

It's saving the output successfully, but instead of adding a value of 10 to the original score, it's creating a whole new score and starting from 0 again. Does this make sense?

I've tried changing the JavaScript to count up from the value of 0

```js
let score = localStorage.getItem("score") || 0;
```

I've also tried tweaking the score value

```js
        if(this.classList.contains("first-click")) {
            score = scoreCounter + 10;
```

I've tried looking through various StackOverflow and other web resources for similar problems but have struggled to found any answer that fits what I'm trying to achieve. Can anyone offer any advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the string you get from [`localStorage.getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) to a number. This can be done with the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus).

```js
let score = +localStorage.getItem("score") || 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is actually working!

The only problem I am now facing is that the updates are not made to the site in 'real-time' but only appear upon refresh. Can you determine why this would be, and how I can make the counter count up on the live page?

Comment: @Zabrake Set `scoreCounter.textContent = score;` in the click event handler.

Comment: thank you - this works! The only issue with it being in amongst the Event Handler is that now, after refreshing the page, the score does not appear (is entirely invisible) until you've actually clicked one of the buttons, at which point it appears. Any advice? I won't pester you any more, I promise! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Zabrake I didn't mean move the `scoreCounter.textContent = score;` statement. You need to set it both outside the event listeners (on page load) and in the event handler.

Comment: Hi again. Thanks so much, you are an absolute genius! This has solved my problem, and I'm so excited to start styling the button and making the site more interesting for people. Woo!

Comment: @Zabrake Glad to help. Good luck with your site.